# MySQL: joins, The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, join, union

I know there are more questions about this but I can`t find the right answer for me.

This is my query:

```
$query = $mysql->query("(
                        SELECT questions.*, tags.tagData
                        FROM questions
                        LEFT JOIN tags
                        ON questions.id = tags.questId
                        )
                        UNION (
                        SELECT users.username
                        FROM users
                        LEFT JOIN questions
                        ON users.id = questions.ownerId
                        )
                    ");
```

I select all the questions in the table questions, also the tags but I save the ownerId as the id of the owner and I want the username to display. Now I get this error:

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking for a `join` rather than `union`? What is the expected output?

Comment: I think you want to join data... if you want to union the data then  you must have same number of columns in each query that you want to union

Comment: @RagingBull I saw it on Google

Comment: `I saw it on Google`? I am sorry, what you mean?

Comment: I search on Google 'mysql joins 2 tables' and then I saw union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to do UNION ? question  table is linked to User and you can use it in JOIN

```
SELECT questions.*, 
tags.tagData,
users.username
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN tags
ON  tags.questId = questions.id 
LEFT JOIN
users ON users.id = questions.ownerId
```

Comment: This wont work, but when I change to SELECT to; SELECT questions.*, users.username, tags.tagData it works!

Comment: Ok good, but with your select and what I gave , the difference I see is position of username column in display. Also its always better to select only required fields not *

Comment: Yeah but I need every fields from questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
 `SELECT questions.*, tags.tagData
            FROM questions
            LEFT JOIN tags
            ON questions.id = tags.questId
            )
            UNION (
            SELECT users.username,questions.*
            FROM users
            LEFT JOIN questions
            ON users.id = questions.ownerId
            )`
```